# Codename One: How to increase height of dialog

Tags: codenameone

[image]I have developed app using Codename one.I want to set specific height of dialog because my text overidden while displaying message in dialog body .what should I do for that?
Thanks in Advance?

I have added image in which first image is original image and second one is cut image which is displaying on screen while using infinite progress bar. my code is "Dialog ipDialog = new InfiniteProgress().showInifiniteBlocking();  ipDialog.Dispose()" I want whole image on screen like original image.
can you help me to solved this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Dialog` `show` method that accepts `int` values to determine the distance from the edges. But normally this is a matter of the text sizing and dialog construction.

Also make sure you are showing the `Dialog` from the EDT thread.

Comment: My code is like this " Dialog ipDialog = new InfiniteProgress().showInifiniteBlocking();" I have to increase the hieght of InfiniteProgress bar.

Comment: Could not find method as you mention the solution .Can you provide the sample code to display message long (minimum 100 characters) message in dialog .

Comment: How to dispose dialog ? dialog.dispose() does not work

Comment: That's the infinite progress. It's transparent but covers the whole screen. What sort of look are you interested in. The answer varies depending on that...

Comment: my infinite progress is getting cut from bottom.I have to increase height of this so i can get whole progress bar

Comment: It seems that you created an image for the infinite progress whose center is offset so when our algorithm rotates the image it gets cropped.

Comment: Creating an image that's properly centered and square so when we rotate it you won't get anything cropped.